# how to draw squares (with different sizes) using jquery / bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to draw something that looks like the following, using jQuery / bootstrap (for spanning) and some sort of binding using angular (but angular is not really important here).

Questions:

1. Does anyone knows how to render something that looks like that?
2. I target 10 squares per row (span between 1 to 3 cubes), but I'm not sure how do I know how many rows can I fit in it. Does anyone have any idea? How can I match it to a given resolution?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about just dynamically creating elements with percentage based dimensions using JQuery? 
I would add the search box using z-index to layer it on top of the grid

Another option is to use some template based framework like Knockout to bind the grid from some data source

Comment: i'm not worried about the search box, that easy...just trying to figure out an easy for to do the squares